# Use ReportingService API to read custom data source credentials

Tags: api, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2008

We have an SQL 2008 R2 server running reporting services and I would like to identify reports that use specific credentials to connect to a data source.  In this situation, the reports connect to the data source using a custom data source with a specific user account that has the proper security on the SQL server to run the reports.

Plan plan was to query [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog] to get a list of reports.  Then run it through the code below to identify the reports using credentials I'm interested in.  All of this would be done in an SSIS package.

Using the ReportingService API, I can read the user name of the credentials  in the connection strings of shared data sources.  The code is listed below.  However, in my case, I need to load the data source credentials from a custom data source specific to the report, not a shared data sources.  The GetDataSourceContents method doesn't seem to support this.  If I supply the report name & path instead of the shared data source, it generates an error.

Is there another way to approach this?  We have hundreds of reports, so using the UI to look this information up would be impractical.

Thanks in advance.

NOTE: "web_service" is the web service reference to the report server (http://[servername]/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx?WSDL)

```
Dim rs As New web_service.ReportingService2005()
rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Dim ds_def As web_service.DataSourceDefinition

ds_def = rs.GetDataSourceContents("/Data Sources/data_source_1")

With MyCredentialsOutputBuffer
    .AddRow()
    .UserName = ds_def.UserName
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to pull down the rdl content and parse it:(

Embedded data source information is stored in the .rdl and not a shared data set item obtained via the api. Even then you can't retrieve data source passwords.

Comment: The ReportServer.dbo.DataSource table contains data about custom data sources for specific reports including what appears to be the credentials in binary.  This led me to believe the custom data source credentials were stored outside of the rdl report definition file.  But, I'll try looking in the rdl file.

Comment: UPDATE:  Looks like parsing the rdl file wil not work.  The rdl file points to a shared data source.  I confirmed this my looking at it in BIDS.  However, the report on the report server uses a custom data source.  The actual custom data source connection string and credentials are stored in the ReportServer.dbo.DataSource table.  Doesn't look like there's any way of getting to this.